# How to implement Undo function

Tags: c#, undo

I'm writing a program called Flipper which has 3x3 cells for the puzzle. Each cell(button) has green color at initial. When Click certain cell, that cell and its adjacent cells flip(change color). And another requirement is the undo function, which is back to previous stage. I have no idea how to implement this. These are the main things happens in the game.

```
public Puzzle(Form1 form1)
{
    buttons = new Button[3, 3] { { form1.button1, form1.button2, form1.button3 }, 
                                 { form1.button4, form1.button5, form1.button6 }, 
                                 { form1.button7, form1.button8, form1.button9 } };
    //button reference from form1
}
public void reset()
{
   //reset all the colors of buttons in the puzzle to lime
}

public void FlipCells(int row, int col)
{        
   //when certain button is clicked(this event is done in the form1.cs), say for (0,0) change color of cell (0,0),///(0,1) and (1,0) by calling changeColor method
}

public void changeColor(int row, int col)
{
    //test current color of the cell, and change it
}
```

I'm asking to implement the undo function in a class called Undo. Any ideas is appreciated!!!

Answer (score 5):

A single undo can be implemented by knowing what changed with the last operation.

As it turns out, undoing a flip can be done by... flipping it again.  So just remember your last move, and repeat it!

You can do this as many times as you like to the initial state of the game if you remember *every* move.  You can do this by creating a stack of moves that you push as you move, and pop as you undo.

More generally, to undo, you need to do 3 things:

1. For every action a user can make, make an inverse action that will undo it.
2. Every time a user makes an action, remember it so you know which inverse action to take (if needed).
3. When the user indicates he wants an undo, match the last thing he did with its inverse action, and execute it.

Sometimes, it is very difficult to create an inverse action.  In these cases, it becomes easier to just store the state of the program before the action is executed, then reload it when the user wants an undo.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of options for implementing the undo functionality.

Since this is homework, I'll just point you to the `Stack` data structure. Stack is last-in, first-out. Think of it as a stack of papers on a table.

When a player flips a square, you make a note of it and add it to the stack (called "push"). The player flips another square: you make another note and then push to the top of the stack.

When "undo" is requested, which operation do you want to undo? The most recent one -- so you draw from the top of the stack (called "pop"). Calling Stack.Pop() will return topmost (most recent) item from the stack and remove that item from the stack.

That should be enough to get you going -- figure out what you need in the stack and you're almost done.

Further reading:
`Stack`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.stack.aspx
`Stack<T>`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3278tedw.aspx

Answer (score 1):

perhaps think about what would happen when you 'undo' a move. all the ones you just flipped are flipped back (or again) assuming you only have two colours that is

Answer (score 1):

Implement Command pattern. where you actually keep track of your commands in some sort of dictionary or array or stack and then undo

visit this link http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/sharped.aspx

Answer (score 1):

All tough  it is probably overkill in your situation the Memento Design Pattern is a standard way for implementing undo (and redo) functionality.

A Memento will save the current state of an object and will have a restore function that will reverse the changes on the object it's linked to.

So in your case a Memento would save the state of the board (each color for each cell) and when applied to a board it will set the colors.

Answer (score 0):

If you have only two colors than undo is not different than changeColor for the cell that you lass called it for.
So all you have to do is to store (in member variables) the last column and row for which the changeColor was called and in the Undo function make another call to changeColor with the stored values.